# wildcard selector in LESS not working

Tags: css, less

Not sure if LESS support wildcard selector with *. I want to override bootstrap's col padding so I do

`.col-*` (I even tried .col-*-*) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's not a valid CSS selector in the first place...

Comment: There is no wildcard for classnames. You could use `[class^="col-"]`

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that there *is* such a selector, judging by the fact that you're not convinced despite what you tried clearly not working. Where did you get this impression? Did somebody or some website tell you?

Answer (score 7):

What you probably confused here is the ["universal selector" `*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors), which matches any element of any given type (=tag name).

A true wildcard selector is neither available in CSS nor any preprocessor i know of, but you have a lot of other options to do fuzzy selections with [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

For your specific case, all of the following would work:

```
[class^="col"] /* begin with "col" */

[class*="col"] /* contains "col" */

[class|="col"] /* starts with "col" followed by "-" */
```

Note, that attribute selectors are not the best performance-wise (which however doesn't really matter if you're not concerned about performance in the first place).